# VS2010 does not find #include via environmental variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost

I'm currently running into a problem that drives me a little bit mad. I hope it's a little stupid mistake on my side.

For convenience, I added an environmental variable in Windows 7, `VS_BOOST_INCLUDE_HEADER` with the value set to `D:\01_Programs\boost_1_55_0\`. My VC C++ include directories contain `$(VS_BOOST_INCLUDE_HEADER)`.

**Remark:** I changed that variable this morning, but I've rebooted my computer since than multiple times.

Now my VS project complains it can't find any of the boost includes anymore, e.g. `<boost/asio.hpp>`. If I add the whole path manually to the include paths (adding `D:\01_Programs\boost_1_55_0\` as text to my VC C++ include directories), everything works as expected.

To avoid a simple typo, I added a post-build event:

```
echo $(VS_BOOST_INCLUDE_HEADER)
```

That works as expected:

```
1>PostBuildEvent:
1>  D:\01_Programs\boost_1_55_0\
```

All my other environmental variables still work as expected, even those that were renamed this morning as well.

Any ideas?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered that the build-settings maybe doesn't support environment variable substitution everywhere?

Comment: Thank you for your response. But if that is the case in here, why was it working yesterday? And why are all the other environmental variables in my VC++ directories still working?

Comment: You might want to use common property sheets for the projects and just use that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It supports it well enough for header paths though.

Comment: @Blutkoete Have you tried removing/readding the variable? Are you adding a system or a user variable? (Not on windows currently, but IIRC there's two categories, if you do that in the Configuration panel).

Comment: I created a new project ... it evaluates the environmental variable without any problems. So it appears that there is simply something really wrong in that one solution, so I think I'll just use the full path in that one project and don't waste any more of my and your time.

Comment: @JBL: Thank you for that simple idea ... now I'm even more puzzled. I removed the variable, now there is no path to any of my Boost directories anymore, and the project still compiles (even after cleaning it). It seems I don't understand the inner workings of VS2010.

Comment: @all: After removing and readding the variable multiple times, everything seems to work again. There appears to be some type of caching that survives computer reboots, VS2010 restarts and solution cleaning. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late to the party, but a possible scenario is when you

- run VS as administrator
- adjusted a User environment variable

Then it would make some sense for VS to see the System environment only and still use the old value.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use property sheets the msdn has clear [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc(v=vs.100).aspx)

> "If you have a common, frequently used set of properties that you want
>   to apply to multiple projects, you can use Property Manager to capture
>   them in a reusable property sheet file"

Under the view menu, chose property manager and add a new sheet.
You can then make your project inherit its settings from this property sheet, thereby just setting this in one place.